# R character string to a variable

Tags: r, excel, function, variables, character

I am new to R. I am using excel with R (Not RExcel). The reason I am using excel with R is so that other users that aren't familiar with R can just run the code and don't need to learn R. 
 I have created a mathematically model for calculating uncertainty on a value. The uncertainty model requires the function used to calculate the value. 
The data is taking from an Excel workbook using XLConnect. In Excel there is a cell to input the function, eg. (a+b)/c . When the function is brought into R the function is a character. I want to convert this character to a function.
Thank you in advance, 
Niall

Comment: What work have you accomplished to this point?

Comment: Sounds like you would need the dreaded `eval(parse(...))`. Just keep in mind that arbitrary input is a security risk.

Comment: I am using the Kragten method to calculate the uncertainty. The code is inputting the data values from excel and calculating the uncertainties. I can insert the function from the editor and it works. I want to make the code so that a person who is unfamiliar with R can implement the kragten method on there results and just display the result back in excel.

Comment: like rolly says, you can do `a <- 1; b <- 1; c <- 2; eval(parse(text = "(a+b)/c"))`